# Counting the number of nodes in a level of a binary search tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, nodes

Like the title says, I want to count the nodes in for any given level of the tree. I already know how to make member functions for counting all the nodes of the tree, just not sure how to approach a specific level. Here's what I've tried. Any help is appreciated.

First parameter is a point to a character array inputted by the user. root is a private variable representing the "oldest" node.

```
int TreeType::GetNodesAtLevel(ItemType* itemArray, int level)
{
    TreeNode* p = root;

    if (itemArray == NULL)
        return;
    if (level == 0)
    {
        cout << p->info << " ";
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        GetNodesAtLevel(itemarray->left, level); //dereference in one and not the other was just testing 
        GetNodesAtLevel(*itemarray->right, level); //neither seems to work
    }
}
```

Comment: There happens to be a fairly simple way to do this kind of a thing. Just take out a blank sheet of paper, and write down using brief, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, here, but always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is by using a queue (employing level order traversal - BFS). Now follow this:

Take two variables, count_level and count_queue (keeping total nodes in a queue).

for a tree like this:

```
               A 
              / \
             B   C
            / \   \
           K   L   D
                   /
                  E
```

initially `count_level = 0` and `count_queue = 0`. Now:

1. Add a node to the queue(at this point A, increment `count_queue` to *1*).
2. Now when you find `count_level = 0` do this -> `count_level = count_queue`.
3. Add the kid nodes while dequeuing till the `count_level` becomes 0. So at this point the follow step **2** and that will give you the no of nodes at level beneath what just has been processed.